# Show Active terms from vocabulary using taxonomy menu

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

**What i want**: *Active* terms of vocabulary in main menu.

**What i have done** so far:

1. I have used taxonomy_menu module.
2. Created taxonomy(Category).
3. Added "Status" field having boolean values (0 = Inactive, 1 = Active).
4. Added two terms in Category(Cat1 and Cat2).
5. Cat1 = Active, Cat2 = Inactive.
6. Configured menu from "Edit vocabulary" section.

**Problem**: All terms of vocabulary are included in main menu. I want that only those terms whose `Status = Active` should be displayed in main menu.

Answer (score 0):

The process to make `taxonomy_menu` module aware of your `status` field seems hard to accomplish, particularly if you need - as you probably would - the taxonomy menu rebuilt when a `status` value changes.

A possibly easier solution would be to act at the theme level, adding a `.inactive` class to inactive items and make it hidden in css. Since Taxonomy Menu module does nothing about themeing, this should be dealt with with Menu module theme functions. So you'll end up writing a (e.g.) `CUSTOM_menu_link()`  function in which you'll need to test if the link is coming from a taxonomy generated menu (not sure how you can do that, anyway) for every menu item of your site and then, if this is the case, load the term, test the `status` field and act accordingly. Not exactly an elegant solution, and quite an overhead.

If possible, I'd rather suggest you use the built-in feature to enable or disable menu items from the admin interface at `admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu`, after configuring your taxonomy-menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this module:
**https://www.drupal.org/project/termstatus**

> This module adds a status-flag to taxonomy terms. Using this flag it is possible to specify whether terms should be published or not. Users with the appropriate permission may access unpublished terms.